# prefix for "possible", "supposed", "potential" etc.?

Tags: terminology, prefixes, neologisms

I am looking for a prefix to express the meaning of something *possibly* belonging to a class / category, or being a candidate for the concept in question.

For instance, a "[...]-solution" would be some statement or proposition that *could be* a solution for a given question, albeit its status of being so or not has still to be established. A "[...]-pathogen" would be a germ whose pathogenic character is still unclear; a "[...]-perpetrator" an alleged perpetrator and so forth. (Actually, I am mostly interested in a more abstract use of the prefix-root-combination).

The prefix should function in the same way as "pseudo-", "quasi-" etc. It would be nice to find something of Greek or Latin origin, but other proposals are fine as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't think there is such a prefix. Why not use an adjective?

Comment: You're talking about [Modality](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) here. Modals are very peculiar and there are so many of them because they're quite different in affordances and uses. As Cerberus suggested, it's more efficient to use an adjective, rather than depending on the vagaries of fossilized morphology. Luckily, there appears to be none. _A likely/probably/possible/conceivable solution/perpetrator/pathogen_ expresses variation in expectation of likelihood (and doesn't allow the author to escape responsibility for the expectation).

Comment: @Cerberus Great site, glad to be here! Using an adjective would usually be fine, but will not work well in the specific usage I have in mind.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, what I am looking for is a modal prefix, or a prefix-marker for modality. The degree of likelihood is less relevant in this context.  If all commenters agree that no such marker exists, that would already be a clarifying answer in its own right ...

Comment: Within limits, there is the suffix _-able/-ible_.

Comment: @megob: Now I am wondering about the specific usage you have in mind and why you decided on it...

Comment: I know of no such prefix. I use the adjective _putative_ for many such cases.

Comment: I scanned the [English prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_prefixes) wikipedia article and didn't see anything like what you're looking for. I'm also curious of the specific use case you have in mind.

Comment: Not a prefix, but scare quotes (and the accompanying intonation and gesture!) sometimes serve this role:  The "pathogen" behind mad cow disease; the "perpetrator" was observed near the scene.  Interestingly it's the very vagueness of these scare quotes that makes them so annoying, which makes me think that John L is on the right track in preferring something more specific (and thus more useful).

Comment: @Cerberus (and Ben): it's just that it has to be a *single term* and not some kind of compound expression. I need it for a piece of philosophy I'am working on, where possible phenomena have a similar status as evident ones, and questions the same as propositions.  
The term has to be very compact, short, and handy; and the prefix would ideally be productive, so as to recombine with other roots. A compound expression would be too technical as well, as this is a more poetic kind of philosophy.

Comment: @Merk Yes, what I am looking for is indeed some kind of gestural marking, more than semantical marking. Vagueness would be ok, but scare quotes communicate a different stance (of the speaker) than the one needed. The device of my dreams would be a morpheme with a gestural modal value. But alas, that's not supplied for by our linguistic conventions ...

Comment: @megob How about using ◇?  The diamond operator indicates epistemic possibility.

Comment: @megob Failing that, since it seems like the prefix you want may not exist, why not make one up?  As long as you tell people what you mean, it should be fine.

Comment: @snailboat yes, both options are something that I consider in fact. Problem with a symbol is that it has no phonetic equivalent (or this would have to be defined). An artificial / constructed prefix could be the most workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The most common phrasing is simply using "possible". It isn't a prefix but it is rather clear:

> This is a possible solution to our bug problem.
>
> John Doe is a possible suspect in the ongoing mystery of the missing cheese.

It isn't as sexy as a prefix would be but English doesn't always offer us exactly what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Does or can 'would-be' accomplish what you want?

The [online OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/would--be?q=would-be) says 'would-be' is "often derogatory" and the only examples are of people who 'would-be' what they are not.

The OED I have installed on notebook has the same definition but without the example, and without saying it is often derogatory. (My local and the online version are usually identical.)

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would-be) gives the definition as "desiring, intending, professing, or having the potential to be "

"Would-be" does usually refer to a person -- basically, an older form of 'wannabe' -- but there's no reason it couldn't be used (at least with a bit of anthropomorphic license) to describe the potential of an inanimate thing to be something it has not yet proven itself to be. In this case, because the word is typically association with a person, it also subtlety points to those behind the efforts to realize that potential.

Comment: "would-be" seems (often) derogatory to me as well. "Could-be" would be [!] a better solution probably - but both are too long. Maybe I should contract this to "coubby"? Coubbypathogene ... Coubbyperpetrator ... ; ) - it's a coubbysolution at least.